# R : How to show a Save File Dialog to save my file in gWidgets

Tags: r, gwidgets

I want to save my file by GUI Save wizard in gWidgets.

From **Save Wizard** I want to say as we can choose file with **file.choose()**, **similarly** how we can save our file using any save wizard in R gWidgets

Kindly give suggestion

Comment: require similar functionality of "save file dialog" as in c#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: You can't. 
Long answer: you can by making your own menu.

To do that create, the graphics device passing `no_popup=TRUE` to the constructor.

Then you are free to add your own popup menu. The one in ggraphics is basically this (pointing you to `gfile` as Thomas did):

```
library(gWidgets)
g = ggraphics(cont=gwindow(), no_popup=TRUE)

l <- list()
l$copyAction <- gaction("Copy", "Copy current graph to clipboard", icon="copy",
                        handler=function(h, ...) copyToClipboard(obj))
l$printAction <- gaction("Save", "Save current graph", icon="save",
                         handler=function(h,...) {
                           fname <- gfile(gettext("Filename to save to"), type="save")
                           if(nchar(fname)) {
                             if(!file.exists(fname) || gconfirm(gettext("Overwrite file?")))
                               svalue(obj) <- fname
                           }
                         })

add3rdMousePopupmenu(g, l)
```

Comment: Error in (function (h, ...)  : could not find function "copyToClipboard"
now what changes i have to make so that this error will resolve

Comment: You wanted to modify things? Either remove the copy action (which is a windows specific thing as written) or replace with something to your liking.

Comment: is there any method to memorize the last save location?

Comment: thanks @jverzani for all your support, Now I am able to control over this.

Comment: Is there something similar to `copyToClipboard` in `gWidgets2` ?

Comment: Using `no_popup=TRUE` there's still the default popupmenu with `gWidgets2`.

Comment: I just pushed both `no_popup` and `copyToClipboard` features to ggraphics. (Untested though).